# Container does not reflect MediaReader setting

Tags: java, ffmpeg, xuggler

I would like my reader to be able to handle audio, when it does not start with the video; hence the setting of "AddDynamicStreams". How do I get the container to recognize the setting of the reader from which it originated? Is there a flag or some other property that I need to set?

```
String inputUrl = "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/myapp/mystream live=1 buffer=1";
IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputUrl);
reader.setCloseOnEofOnly(false);
reader.setQueryMetaData(false);
// we want dynamic addition of streams
reader.setAddDynamicStreams(true);
// this shows "true"
log.debug("Reader can dynamically add streams: {}", reader.canAddDynamicStreams());
// get the container
IContainer container = reader.getContainer();
// this shows "false"
log.debug("Container can dynamically add streams: {}", container.canStreamsBeAddedDynamically());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since development on Xuggler has ended, this is moot.